# How to access system time finer than 1 second on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, time

The system time function time(0) gives me a resolution of 1 second, right?

Is there a finer-grained function?

**I'm using it to determine the time interval between two events.**

A line of code would help me greatly. It makes it easier to have something concrete to hang the concept on when I look in the official documentation.

Comment: +1 for putting actual code like I asked. Thanks @zoul.

Comment: Holy smokes, my question is already showing up in google results for "system time(0)"

Comment: This is important: the value is returned from CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent: is a double in units of seconds but the resolution is not in seconds. It is sub-millisecond. I  find the Apple documentation misleading on this point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/index.html):

```
CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
// do something you want to measure
CFAbsoluteTime end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"operation took %2.5f seconds", end-start);
```

Should you find `CFAbsouteTime` too verbose, you can simply use `double` instead.

Comment: Can you use that in a sentence?

Comment: How would you get intervals of less than a second from that?

Comment: The returned value is a double, simply multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds or multiply by 1e6 to get μs.

Comment: I was getting a 0 result when I left the 'do something' line blank. It turns out the timer can't measure such a small interval. Once I put some statements in between, I got a result. Thanks for putting actual working code instead of referencing a method name or document link. Sometimes the docs are too abstract for me at first.

Comment: I’m so used to that function that at first it did not occur to me why an example would be needed, sorry. Happy hacking!

Comment: It's easy for programmers to forget how many thousands of bits of knowledge they've absorbed over time. For me just in the last 4 months the Apple docs have gone from completely opaque pages of line noise to useful but muddy guides. Some things I get, for the rest I consult Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

`NSDate` has  `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method, which returns `double` ("sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years" Apple says).

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
…
NSTimeInterval duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
```

Comment: do you know how to use that to get the difference between two times?

Comment: use timeIntervalSince1970 and then compare. It's given in seconds, but with many decimal places - so you can multiply by 1000 to get msec, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Did you look for `gettimeofday()`?  That's the main POSIX function for sub-second resolution timing analogous to `time()`.

See [Native App Development for the iPhone](http://www.volkerroth.com/tecn-iphone.html) for an illustration of its use.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval
                       target:self selector:@selector(drawView) userInfo:nil
                       repeats:YES];
```

That's a snippet from the OpenGL app template.  If you're looking for a high resolution timer, it's probably what you need.